# How do I compile VASP 5.4.1 on a Cray XC

Tags: compilation, cray

I want to compile the latest version of VASP 5 (5.4.1) on a Cray XC MPP machine. Does anyone have the settings I can use? The VASP distribution does not come with an example for Cray.

The build system has changed from the 5.3.5 version.

Answer (score 1):

Full compilation instructions can be found on the ARCHER (http://www.archer.ac.uk) website at:

http://www.archer.ac.uk/documentation/software/vasp/compiling_5-4-1-phase2.php

But in brief:

1. Download and patch the source code
2. Switch to Intel programming environment and load the fftw module:

   ```
   module swap PrgEnv-cray PrgEnv-intel
   module load fftw
   ```
3. Create "makefile.include" with the following settings:

   ```
   # Precompiler options
   CPP_OPTIONS= -DMPI -DHOST=\"CrayXC-Intel\" \
                -DIFC \
                -DCACHE_SIZE=2000 \
                -DPGF90 \
                -Davoidalloc \
                -DMPI_BLOCK=8000 \
                -DscaLAPACK \
                -Duse_collective \
                -DnoAugXCmeta \
                -Duse_bse_te \
                -Duse_shmem \
                -Dtbdyn

   CPP        = fpp -f_com=no -free -w0  $*$(FUFFIX) $*$(SUFFIX) $(CPP_OPTIONS)

   FC         = ftn
   FCL        = ftn

   FREE       = -free -names lowercase

   FFLAGS     = -assume byterecl
   OFLAG      = -O3 -ip -fno-alias -unroll-aggressive -opt-prefetch -use-intel-optimized-headers -no-prec-div
   OFLAG_IN   = $(OFLAG)
   DEBUG      = -O0

   MKL_PATH   = $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64
   BLAS       =
   LAPACK     =
   BLACS      =
   SCALAPACK  =

   OBJECTS    = fftmpiw.o fftmpi_map.o fftw3d.o fft3dlib.o
   INCS       =

   LLIBS      = ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_blas95_lp64.a ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a \
                ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a  \
                -Wl,--start-group ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_intel_lp64.a \
                ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_core.a \
                ${MKL_PATH}/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a  -Wl,--end-group

   OBJECTS_O1 += fft3dfurth.o fftw3d.o fftmpi.o fftmpiw.o
   OBJECTS_O2 += fft3dlib.o

   # For what used to be vasp.5.lib
   CPP_LIB    = $(CPP)
   FC_LIB     = $(FC)
   CC_LIB     = cc
   CFLAGS_LIB = -O
   FFLAGS_LIB = -O1
   FREE_LIB   = $(FREE)

   OBJECTS_LIB= linpack_double.o getshmem.o

   # Normally no need to change this
   SRCDIR     = ../../src
   BINDIR     = ../../bin
   ```
4. Compile the code

   ```
   make all
   ```